# Get a gender of a particular person in SPARQL...?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am very new to these topics. I read the sparql documents and I am trying to get a gender of a particular person. Say for example I want **Larry_Page gender**. I was able to getting all the properties of lary_page (Based on the following page: [`http://dbpedia.org/resource/Larry_Page`](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Larry_Page)) but it doesn't have any property called Gender. So how can I get the gender of a particular person...??? Can any one tell me the answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBpedia is not a particularly complete dataset. It is well possible that for the person you are looking at, there simply is no gender property of any kind defined - similar to the situation outlined in the answer in [this thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20160708184723/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/12221/query-that-filters-results-from-dbpedia-by-gender).

Even if there is, keep in mind that it can be expressed by a variety of properties and values, so you would have to check all of them to at least use the data where it is defined. A quick check shows me at least the following properties that may store the information you are interested in:

- [`http://dbpedia.org/ontology/gender`](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/gender)
- [`http://dbpedia.org/ontology/sex`](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/sex)
- [`http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/gender`](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/#term_gender)

Note that some of these may link to other resources such as [`Male`](http://dbpedia.org/page/Male) or [`Female`](http://dbpedia.org/page/Female), whereas others will simply contain strings such as `male` or `female` (the FOAF specification explicitly says

> typically but not necessarily 'male' or 'female'

).

---

The following query, for example, returns the gender of [Scheherazade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheherazade):

```
SELECT ?gl
WHERE {
  dbpedia:Scheherazade dbpedia-owl:gender ?g.
  ?g rdfs:label ?gl.
  FILTER(lang(?gl) = "en").
}
```

Likewise, the following query lists the name and gender of a number of persons:

```
SELECT ?pn ?gl
WHERE {
  ?person dbpedia-owl:gender ?g.
  ?person a dbpedia-owl:Person.
  ?person dbpprop:name ?pn.
  {
    ?person dbpedia-owl:gender dbpedia:Male.
  } UNION {
    ?person dbpedia-owl:gender dbpedia:Female.
  }.
  ?g rdfs:label ?gl.
  FILTER(lang(?gl) = "en").
}
```

However, this query can capture only those persons for which the respective type and gender attributes are set. Larry Page will never appear in that list with the current dataset as it does not have the respective gender property. As another practical example see this very similar query, which returns a different (non-empty) list:

```
SELECT ?pn ?gl
WHERE {
  ?person dbpedia-owl:gender ?g.
  ?person a dbpedia-owl:Person.
  ?person dbpprop:name ?pn.
  {
    ?person dbpedia-owl:gender dbpedia:Man.
  } UNION {
    ?person dbpedia-owl:gender dbpedia:Woman.
  }.
  ?g rdfs:label ?gl.
  FILTER(lang(?gl) = "en").
}
```

Yet another query returns yet another list:

```
SELECT ?pn ?gl
WHERE {
  ?person ?gender ?gl.
  ?person a dbpedia-owl:Person.
  ?person dbpprop:name ?pn.
  FILTER((?gl = "Female"@en) || (?gl = "Male"@en)).
}
```

**EDIT:** DBpedia's default namespace prefixes have changed since writing this answer. The mapping is as follows:

- `dbpedia` -> `http://dbpedia.org/resource/` (now `dbr`)
- `dbpedia-owl` -> `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/` (now `dbo`)
- `dbpprop` -> `http://dbpedia.org/property/` (now `dbp`)

Comment: Hay thanx yar. I am using DBPEDIA ontology. I tried different approaches but I was not able to get the gender of a particular person. If possible can you please provide a simple query to get a gender of a particular person (Use my example I mean get a gender of Larry_Page). Please provide sample example. I was stuck over here.

Comment: @Amar: There is no general way to get the gender of a given person - as I explained in my answer, it requires looking for a variety of properties (a simple query will thus certainly not suffice), and in some cases - possibly, Larry Page is one of them - it may be downright impossible as the respective information about the person's gender is simply not contained in the DBpedia data.

Comment: @Amar: I have added a sample, though I am not sure it is what you want.

Comment: Thanx Mapper. So you are saying dbpedia dataset itself doesn't have that property for some resources. Is it right...??? So I need to traverse the links and I need to get that value. Is it right Mapper...??? Why I am asking these question is I am trying to retrieving the data for my application testing. I need real time test data. That's why I choose the DBPEDIA. I have a person entity and it has a property called gender. But here I was able to retrieve the properties of a person but not fully. So how can I solve these kinds of problems...??? Can you please help me on these Mapper...???

Comment: @Amar: Right, the records in the DBpedia dataset are not uniformly structured. Some person records have that gender attribute you found, others have a different one, yet others have several, and yet others have none at all. Your best chance is to retrieve all of those attributes that you can find and then try to figure out the gender from that combined data.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper these queries 1,2,3 are not working (empty results) on http://dbpedia.org/snorql/. I am a newbie and I am trying stuffs out, do you know why its returning an empty results? I included the "PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>" namespace in full.

Comment: @fanbondi: It seems DBpedia's default namespace prefixes have changed. For the current list, [check out this URL](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl). It appears that `dbpedia-owl` has been renamed to `dbo`, and `dbpedia` has been renamed to `dbr`. If you make these replacements in the first query, for instance, the result set is not empty. I have just tried this with the first two queries from my answer and it worked.

Comment: @fanbondi: I have edited my answer to include a mapping of used prefixes to the actual URI prefixes. Note that in your particular case, one likely source of confusion is that the SNORQL frontend you link to includes the additional `PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>` declaration, which declares the `dbpedia` prefix *differently* from what it used to be (and from what I am using it in this answer). In this answer, `dbpedia` maps to `http://dbpedia.org/resource/`, *not* to `http://dbpedia.org/`.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, that is helpful. Actually, it was really confusing as a beginner but I am getting on with it step by step.