# sparql / dbpedia regarding extracting rdf:type person

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia, linked-data

I'd like to extract all the dpbedia entries of rdf:type person using some things called dbpedia and sparql which I barely understand.

I was mostly successful with the following (varying the offset). Is there a better way? I'd like to basically get all the examples of people from the English wikipedia.

```sql
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?name ?birth ?description ?person WHERE {
     ?person dbo:birthDate ?birth .
     ?person foaf:name ?name .
     ?person rdfs:comment ?description .
     FILTER (LANG(?description) = 'en') .
}
ORDER BY ?name
OFFSET 100
```

Comment: It's not really clear what the question is.  Yes, using ORDER BY and OFFSET (along with LIMIT) is the right way to get the results here, if you're intent on doing it from the webservice.  You could also just download the data, too.  Your query includes many more prefixes than you need.  You only use dbo:, foaf:, and rdfs:, so those are the only ones you need in your query.

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going about it in roughly the right way, though you should OFFSET *and* LIMIT, so that you can paginate the results (and of course, for OFFSET and LIMIT to be useful, you need to keep using the ORDER BY).  You're using more prefixes than you need, though.  You only use three, so you only need to declare those three.  Finally, you can specially ask for things of type **Person**.  There are 1649645 of them.

```sql
select (count(*) as ?n) where {
 ?person a dbo:Person 
}
```

[1649645](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%28count%28*%29%20as%20%3Fn%29%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%3Fperson%20a%20dbo%3APerson%20%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Finally, you should check the languages of strings with **langMatches**, not **=**.  The webservice that you can work with interactively defines some prefixes, so I usually follow those.  You might also want to select only English names, and probably order by the URI, since the names aren't always perfect:

```sql
select ?person ?name ?birth ?description where {
  ?person a dbo:Person ;
          foaf:name ?name ;
          dbo:birthDate ?birth ;
          dbo:abstract ?description
  filter langMatches(lang(?name),'en')
  filter langMatches(lang(?description),'en')
}
order by ?person
offset 100
limit 50
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fperson%20%3Fname%20%3Fbirth%20%3Fdescription%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20a%20dbo%3APerson%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foaf%3Aname%20%3Fname%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3AbirthDate%20%3Fbirth%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3Aabstract%20%3Fdescription%0D%0A%20%20filter%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Fname%29%2C%27en%27%29%0D%0A%20%20filter%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Fdescription%29%2C%27en%27%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aorder%20by%20%3Fperson%0D%0Aoffset%20100%0D%0Alimit%2050&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Of course, if you want lots of data, you might want to just download it and store it locally.  See [**DBpedia 2014 Downloads**](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads2014).

Comment: This does no longer work the prefix dbpedia-owl is not present any more it should be added: PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

Comment: @samy Yup, DBpedia changed its predefined prefixes.  That breaks a lot of old queries.  Evidently backwards compatibility wasn't all that important.

Comment: I just saw in a different question that the new prefixes are: dbpedia -> http://dbpedia.org/resource/ (now dbr)
dbpedia-owl -> http://dbpedia.org/ontology/ (now dbo)
dbpprop -> http://dbpedia.org/property/ (now dbp)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887558/get-a-gender-of-a-particular-person-in-sparql/19890881#19890881
maybe you can update your answer, this would help newcomers to the topic to not get confused because the answers examples do not work

Comment: @samy I have approximately [233 answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1281433+[dbpedia]+is%3Aanswer) about DBpedia at the moment, and it would be very hard to go through and update them all.  I'll certainly accept any suggested edit that uses the incorrect prefixes, though.